# Simulating 3D clothing on human model on the web

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, webgl, game-physics, unreal-engine4

so lately I've been trying to find the best solution to do that, basically what I'm trying to achieve is this:
[image]

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCGHXlLR3l8&feature=youtu.be&t=1057

or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgMuGRCnqXw
(they looks great but doesn't seem to work on web)

So I would like to achieve such a result but on the Web.

I tried to search the web for a whole week, the best thing I could find was these 2 links and this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5acomKAux4 which I'm not sure that works as good as the 2 others.

I also tried to contact Jim Hugunin which is responsible for the insane result in the picture but unfortunately, the guy seems to be absent since January 2018 :\

Have anyone ever experienced doing such a simulation? Do you believe WebGL is capable of rendering such a thing?
Would be very thankful for anyone who could shine some light :)

Comment: This question is off topic for stack overflow as it's basically asking for a library or other offsite solution. Unity (and Unreal) export to HTML and there are cloth solutions for both so that's proof it's *possible* simulate cloth on the web.

Comment: Hi gman, I don't know if you read my entire question or ever tried to accomplish cloth solution in any of these engines, but the default cloth solution in both engines is far from looking like the picture/videos I attached which is soft-body based, the default cloth solution in these engines is mostly good for flags, etc. I'm asking this question here because I hoped to find someone who is as curious as me to try and accomplish such a challenge on the web. what obi cloth does, for example, seems great but it can't work on web

Comment: this is not a forum. Sorry. Stack Overflow has a [set of rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). If you're looking for a discussion or opinions or just other people to talk about a topic this is not the place to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have anyone ever experienced doing such a simulation?

Yes,  there are quite a few on the Unity asset store, but non support webgl yet. If you kindly send them info on webgl / multithreading information, they might consider.

> Do you believe WebGL is capable of rendering such a thing? Would be
>   very thankful for anyone who could shine some light :)

It's possible, but only on a few browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedarraybuffer, someone could probably implement it. It  needs WASM multithreading,  which is currently available in 2019.1+ experimentally - see this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/2019-1.597238/